# PHP json_encode is adding a double quote at the beginning

Tags: php, wordpress

json_encode is adding a double quote at the beginning. Any help is much appreciated

```
$response_array = array("popularity_score" => $popularity_score, "popularity_rating" => $popularity_rating);
$response = json_encode($response_array);
echo $response;
```

Actual Result:

```
"{"popularity_score":13,"popularity_rating":50}
```

Expected Result:

```
{"popularity_score":13,"popularity_rating":50}
```

Comment: You probably are outputing a `"` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: using echo and then the variable

Comment: http://ideone.com/eV1GwA

Comment: use `echo " HERE :: " . $response;` to check if the json encoding is responsible for that extra `"`

Comment: your posted code will return the expected result, your problem is somewhere else

Comment: Here is the output. Double quotes is not inserted by json_encode " HERE :: {"popularity_score":14,"popularity_rating":50}

Comment: Your first `"`, before the word `popularity_score` won't actually be an opening quote, but in fact is [accidentally] the closing quote to a previous quote that you have written in your code beforehand. Most likely, you have forgotten to close the string that is last used before this line.

Comment: @Saravanan the output you just gave proves the double quote is insert BEFORE the json_encode. We'll leave you with it to review your code and find the bug (which is not with the code you have provided)...

Comment: Thanks.Let me review the code